# Gmail filter out all that is not strict mail pattern

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'm needing some help on how to create a filter for Gmail, let me explain my current situation. For some reason I still do not understand Gmail assumes that, for example, if my email is `john.doe@gmail.com` it will consider ANY DOT combination as the same email, so `johndoe@gmail.com`, how can I create a filter that will send any mail that is not strictly to `john.doe@gmail.com` to spam?

Any solution to this will be really great, since there is some people who thinks it's funny to subscribe to some trash using some forged email address that "looks" like mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313?hl=en):

> **Dots don't matter in Gmail addresses**
> If someone accidentally adds dots to your address when emailing you, you'll still get that email. For example, if your email is johnsmith@gmail.com, you own all dotted versions of your address:
>
> john.smith@gmail.com
> jo.hn.sm.ith@gmail.com
> j.o.h.n.s.m.i.t.h@gmail.com
>
> Note: If you use Gmail through work, school, or other organization (like yourdomain.com or yourschool.edu), dots do change your address. To change the dots in your username, contact your **admin**.

If Note part is not applicable in your case then all the mails coming to you are meant to you as dots don't matter in Gmail address. So, you can put filter in the same way like you do for other email address.

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering for your wanted address, but NOT in the from/to field.

E.g. Doesn't have the words:  "John.Doe@gmail.com"

Yes you want the quotes.

Initially you want to give it a label, "BadMail"

Then after some checking, add an action to put it in trash, or in spam.